# Beautiful Soup first child in thia html web scrape

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have an example html in here http://cyberrule.netii.net/1.html
i would like to get first generation children of 
I have tried this

```
nav = soup.find( 'nav' )
child_li = nav.findAll("li", { "class" : "dropdown" })
```

but this one gives me only list with class dropdown.
bottom of the list are missing.
I would like to get all of them in an array for step by step processing.

Comment: got it I can use findChildren(recursive=False)

Comment: If this answered your question, you can write your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the `recursive=False` argument to find the direct children.

```
nav = soup.find( 'nav' )
child_li = nav.ul.find_all("li", recursive=False)
for c in child_li:
    print c.text
```

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument